# Jquery menu acting erratically, bad positioning and general bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a horizontal menu.

What it should be doing is having the elements under it line up along the right side in an orderly fashion. Instead, it jumps throughout page seemingly randomly, and has other issues such as flickering. I've been stuck on making it for awhile and would love some tips to resolve these issues. Here is a **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CUsrS/)** showing the issue, all stripped down.

Thanks.

Here are current issues:

- The submenu does not align perfectly with the right side of main nav even though its offset is calculated by main navs offset + width.
- Flickering(Moderately solved using large borders)
- Elements sometimes doesn't catch mouseover, to reproduce I am moving my mouse all the way down and off and up it and off
- The menu slide out part goes to the bottom right of the page, in a somewhat random order, and continues to move further away (yikes)

Comment: Works for me except the submenus show behind their parents. This can be solved by assigning the z-index manually.

Comment: Try moving your mouse from right to left onto elements, they start to funk out. (Move farther down and to right)

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome Win7, aside from the z-index issue, but that can't be solved by adding z-index to anything as it's an inherited value. Try rebuilding it a different way.

Comment: @jett I have met the following issues: <br/> - the submenus show behind the main menu <br/> - the page shrinks and re-expands when the menu redraws, causing the scrollbars jump. You should solve it by pre-allocating enough space for the menu. <br/> Only after my initial comment, I also noticed: <br/> - the submenu disappears when you hover between submenu items. You can make the `ul` visible and hover it, or you could assign the `li`s a border so that they overlap. <br/> - I have once managed to make the menu disappear completely, stretching the page if NOT hovered. No idea how.

Comment: Yes. It seems the menu slide out part goes to the bottom right of the page, it happens on ff and chrome. This is really my biggest problem, as I have absolutely no idea what would cause this. By waving my mouse on the menu and off it I can reproduce it. Once this happens it continues to move further to the bottom left, sometimes hopping around. Thank you for suggestions, I'm trying them now.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Failing for me on firefox 1.5.1 and chromium on linux. I would prefer to have it align to the right perfectly and this is not working also, so z-index isnt really an issue.

Comment: Also, it sometimes doesn't catch mouseover, to reproduce I am moving my mouse all the way down and off and up it and off.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure of stackoverflows policy on this, but it seems safe, if you'd like to add your solution to the bordering issue I can upvote it as it does solve some of my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the flickering issue is to make the submenu items overlap or touch. This can be done by adding a one-pixel white border to the menu item.

When it comes to the alignment issue (which could have been intended), you need to add (twice) the element's padding and border as the width is inside the padding.